# This equation has no solution in positive integers x,y,z

Tags: number-theory

$3 = \left( 1 - \frac{z}{x+y}\right)\left(\frac{x}{z-y} - 1\right)\left(\frac{y}{z-x} - 1\right)$ has no solution in positive integers x,y,z

The above assertion can be easily proved, if you call upon a famous result.  I offer this as a fun challenge for anyone who wants to try and solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $(x+y)(z-y)(z-x)$ gives you
$$3(x+y)(z-y)(z-x)=(x+y-z)^3.$$
Then, you can simplify this as
$$x^3+y^3=z^3.$$
By [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem), if $x^3+y^3=z^3\ (x,y,z\in\mathbb Z)$, then $xyz=0.$

Since at least one of $x,y,z$ has to be $0$, your equation has no solution in positive integers $x,y,z$.

Comment: @O.C.Riley: So, you changed $x^3+y^3=z^3$ to your expression? These look so different!

Comment: Without hesitating, you took up the challenge, and you noticed that the equation, which I laboured to produce, is unique and unusual.  I applaud you.

Comment: @O.C.Riley: Thanks. As you wrote, it was fun:)